# How do you see all the certs in a .pem file via openSSL?

Tags: openssl

I have a .pem file where three certs make up the certificate chain. I'd like to know an openssl command where it outputs all three certs. I've tried the following command and others but all I get back is one of the three certs, the leaf cert. Please help on what command will just show me the full certificate chain?

`openssl x509 -in identity_smarsh_com.pem -text`

Comment: Not programming or development, and asked numerous times already; see https://serverfault.com/questions/590870/how-to-view-all-ssl-certificates-in-a-bundle  https://serverfault.com/questions/391396/how-to-split-a-pem-file https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/696224/using-openssl-to-display-all-certificates-of-a-pem-file  plus more linked to the last